# how can i get option in doc(path) in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

**Flutter - Firestore**

i have this track in `streamBuilderWidget`

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("usersMsgs").doc(????).collection("chat").snapshots(),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
       return Center(
     child: circulearProgress(),
      );
  } etc.....
```

in doc() part How can i tell him go to path which is contains("123") or contains("456")

**Note : there already one doc("123456") in same collection is existing..**

and those numbers is only as example for real user's Id's

For any help I would be very grateful

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I just give some ideas

1. You can use a textfield and add it inside the doc()
2. Add radio buttons and use the doc()

Comment: thanks saffron but doc() will never ever accept text field , even if it accept i don't think it gonna be perfect in case user want to get in stream , he will never make search in every time he needs to get in